# Variable number of arguments for \newcommand

Tags: macros, parameters

I use the following command to write my matrix variables

```
\newcommand{\mymat}[3]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}^{#2}_{#3}}}
```

Thus #1 is the matrix variable, `#2` is the superscript and `#3` is the subscript. For example `\mymat{A}{T}{i}` would yield the output `$\mathbf{A}^{T}_{i}$`. Most often, the case is that I don't need the subscript and superscript arguments and I end up writing `\mymat{A}{}{}`. Is there a way to make the last two brackets optional?

Comment: `twoopt`, from the `oberdiek` bundle`, does that.

Comment: Yes but it's almost always a bad choice of input syntax (not a technical point, of course).

Comment: `\newcommand{\mymat}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}` and `\mymat{A}^{T}_{i}` is clearer and not more difficult to type.

Comment: Note that `^{}` and `_{}` affect the spacing so it is better to use a markup that does not put in null sub and superscript atoms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `xparse` package which offers great possibilities for defining user commands:

My First attempt:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mymat}{o m o}  
{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
  {\IfNoValueTF{#3}{\mathbf{#2}}{\mathbf{#2}^{#3}}}
  {\IfNoValueTF{#3}{\mathbf{#2}_{#1}}{\mathbf{#2}_{#1}^{#3}}}
}
```

Egregs simpler solution with `IfValueT`

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mymat}{o m o}  
  {%
    \mathbf{#2}\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}\IfValueT{#3}{^{#3}}
  }
```

`m` stands for mandatory argument, `o` for optional.

`IfValueT{argument}{true code}` checks if the argument was given and calls either `true code` or does nothing.

`IfNoValueTF{argument}{true code}{false code}` checks if the argument was not given and calls either {true code} or {false code}

Result (You should maybe add a negative math space `\!` if you have an ***A*** matrix.:
`\mymat{A}[\!\top]`):

```
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \mymat{A}
  \mymat[1]{A}
  \mymat{A}[\top]
  \mymat[1]{A}[\top]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Simpler: `\mathbf{#2}\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}\IfValueT{#3}{^{#3}}`

Comment: Of course! Will edit my answer

Comment: @MaxNoe I suggest to keep both versions, to show different approaches.

Comment: Ok. Now we have both.

Comment: @egreg \mathbf{#1}\IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}\IfValueT{#3}{^{#3}} is this correct?

Comment: You changed the ordee of the arguments.